# I want to convert this data from my spark rdd to a dictonary

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, rdd

The data is like a dictionary but inside square brackets instead,  which make it a list.
The list is the following:

`a = [{'sI': ['17046', '17043'], 'sQ': ['15800', '15789'], 'rid': 572, 'pid': 511, 'uid': 411, 'st': 1594892854.513586, 'et': '16`

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a valid Python list. Others are not able to decide if your list contains only one elem or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your raw data is a one element list then your should only use the zero index and you will get the dictionary.

**Code:**

```
raw_data = [
    {
        "sI": ["17046", "17043"],
        "sQ": ["15800", "15789"],
        "rid": 572,
        "pid": 511,
        "uid": 411,
        "st": 1594892854.513586,
        "et": "16",
    }
]

print("Raw type: {}".format(type(raw_data)))

converted_data = raw_data[0]  # Get the first element of list.

print("Converted type: {}".format(type(converted_data)))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
Raw type: <class 'list'>
Converted type: <class 'dict'>
```

If your list contains more dicts then your can get the dicts one-by-one in a `for` loop. I have written an example for you.

**Code:**

```
raw_data = [
    {
        "sI": ["17046", "17043"],
        "sQ": ["15800", "15789"],
    },
    {
        "sI": ["2", "3"],
        "sQ": ["4", "5"],
    }
]  # This list contains 2 dicts

print("Raw type: {}".format(type(raw_data)))

for item in raw_data:
    print("Type inside loop: {}".format(type(item)))  # Getting dicts one-by-one ("item" variable contains it)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
Raw type: <class 'list'>
Type inside loop: <class 'dict'>
Type inside loop: <class 'dict'>
```